# Is there a R function to make pairwise correlation tests between 2 different subsets?

Tags: r, subset, correlation, pairwise

I have a dataset (con) divided in 2 groups (A and B) and for each sample from group A (1-5), group B has a correspondent sample (1-5), each sample has different measures (zinc, iron, cadmium) pertaining to it.

My intended goal is making a correlation test between A1-B1;A2-B2;A3-B3,...measures.
My question is, is there a way to make such a individual correlation and then trace a linear model graph or if I can just separate the groups and do a `cor.test()` between the two subsets?

I have created two different subsets (conA, conB), using:

```
cor.test(conA$Zinc,conB$Zinc, method="spearman",exact=FALSE)
```

to get the overall correlation for each measure but I wanted to make each pair wise correlation which I don't think it's been done this way.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please give us some toy (dummy) data where we can experiment? This would be quite helpful for us to understand and answer your question.

Comment: "2 different subsets" can have correlation so long as they have the same length and they are tied together logically (such as: date, person, sequence of event, etc). While the logical-tying thing is an "analytical" thing (meaning without it you can still get a number, whether or not it is meaningful or just a statistical _fabrication/lie_), but the former is a requirement. If you look at `stats:::cor.test.default`, one of the first checks if `if (length(x) != length(y))`.

Comment: As Eva hinted: the solution might involve a bit of reshaping of your original dataframe `con`. Please provide this data by pasting the output of `dput(con)` or a sufficient subset, say, five paired observations per group for, say, two outcomes.

Comment: @Eva here you go, sorry for this format but i dont know how to put it in a table  Type Samples Zinc  Iron  Cadmium
A 1 40.4182538494163 4.14246558453983 5.06275257049576
B 1 8.226684025 4.142465585 0.057200545
A 2 40.0059157351504 4.14246558453983 2.49802561608657
B 2 21.89781394 4.142465585 0.057200545
A 3 52.8162770923082 4.14246558453983 9.51114173008322
B 3 3.215615851 4.142465585 0.197002949
A 4 37.2108767466964 8.18085608926247 10.7597595838906
B 4 1.816150512 75.46619229 0.158789084
A 5 52.068752120785 4.14246558453983 5.52795315325597
B 5 13.29312173 35.02115892 0.057200545